# Get default parameters from URL to using php

Tags: php, xml

I have the below url  and need to copy the same parameters on my XML.

URL:

```
http://192.192.192.192/api/captureserver?MessageType=CaptureLookup&MachineName=00321A&RegistrationMark=MRU&DateRange=20171219-20171219.
```

I need to get that MachineName on the XML.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
header ("content-type: text/xml");
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'admin', 'Customer_1') or die("cannot connect");

$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$RegistrationMark = $_GET['RegistrationMark'];


$qr= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `EarlsdonMSIN_anpr_vega` where `RegistrationMark` like '%" .$RegistrationMark. "%'");


$xml.='<MatchRecords>';
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($qr))
{
 $xml.='<MatchLine><id>'.$res['id'].'</id><RegistrationMark>'.$res['RegistrationMark'].'</RegistrationMark><datetime>'.$res['datetime'].'</datetime><time>'.$res['time'].'</time><image_name>'.$res['image_name'].'</image_name></MatchLine>';
}
$xml.='</MatchRecords>';
echo $xml;
?>
```

tried this :

```
$xml.='<MatchLine><id>'.$res['id'].'</id><MachineName>'.$res['MachineName'].'</MachineName><RegistrationMark>'.$res['RegistrationMark'].'</RegistrationMark><datetime>'.$res['datetime'].'</datetime><time>'.$res['time'].'</time><image_name>'.$res['image_name'].'</image_name></MatchLine>';
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want `$_GET['MachineName']`

Comment: You seem to already know how to read from the GET parameters. What's the issue?

Comment: I tried using get but on my XML I am getting just/<MachineName> without  00321A from URL.

Comment: print this $res['MachineName'] before adding into xml string

Comment: @Love-Kesh Or better still `print_r($_GET)` and see what is on your querystring

Comment: Shouldn't it be `...<MachineName>'.$_GET['MachineName'].'</MachineName>...` instead of `<MachineName>'.$res['MachineName'].'</MachineName>`? (**Changed `res` to `_GET`**)

Comment: yes that worked ..Thanks FirstOne..